# How can I retrieve object from DBResultSet (DBAccess) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dbaccess

I have class User.swift:

```
import UIKit
@objc(User)

class User: DBObject {
    dynamic var Sync: NSNumber?
    dynamic var Login: NSString?
    dynamic var Password: NSString?
    dynamic var id_Worker: NSNumber?

static func authorize(login: String, password: String) -> Bool{
    var query = User.query().whereWithFormat("login = %@ and password = %@", withParameters: [login, password.md5])

    var resSet = query.fetch() as DBResultSet

    if resSet.count > 0 {
        var user = resSet[0] as! User
    }

    if resSet.count > 0{
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

}

I want to retrieve User object from DBResultSet. But under the debbuger I get this strange construction:

[image]

How can I retrieve object User from DBResultSet?

Comment: Humm, the interesting thing there is the fact that the table has values, as otherwise the query would not have retrieved any results.   What happens if you "po" a property?  or if you call "po user.fieldData", do you see any values then?

Comment: Yes I can find out the values in fieldData. But what should I do if I want to retrieve it as object? Is it possible? Because I  can not find the object of class User. I only have NSDictionary there.

Comment: Appart from the properties showing as nil, the user object does look to be of type User doe sit not?  The __ObjC.DBObject is just a normal inheritance detail.  I might have missed your problem here?  Because resSet is an array of User class objects, and you are pulling one out and assigning it to "user", which looks like what you wanted?  What are the symptoms you are experiencing when using that object?

Comment: Yes it looks like user object but for some reason the fields of this retrieved object are nil. I want it to be filled with correct values. And this values are in fielddata as nsdictionary.

Comment: For me to know which area to go looking in, if you were to "po user.Login" does it say nil? or have a value?

Comment: Thank you for your patience :) It shows a value when I print it out but for some reason the debugger shows nil everywhere. The question is closed